# 3D game engines in ubuntu

Tags: java, games, 3d, engine

I know this must be one of the many question around the same topic.  But, i want clear mind and new eyes in this.

I am beginning to grasp java for game development for pc and tablet; i cant use unity 3D to i ask for help in choosing a game engine for ubuntu using java as is primary language.  I look around and there a lot i just want to narrow it down a bit.

Thanks in advance and hope for your advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best - and only - Java game engine I know would be [LWJGL](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://lwjgl.org/&ei=73UaU7iMNYWxywOup4HADA&usg=AFQjCNFz3Bro5QbvFFDjTc9B89g1oE2_WQ&bvm=bv.62578216,d.bGQ).

This stands for *Lightweight Java Game Library*. It is a implementation of OpenGL, OpenAL and OpenCL, which are themselfs written in C.

But Java itself is rather unusual and unrecommendated for creating 3D games. It brings a huge loss in performance due to the realtime  interpretation of the Java Byte Code.

You may have a look at C++ instead.